# is there a function in Socket.io or in node js to watch changes in API output?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, node-modules

I'm trying to use socket.io and node js to add reactivity to my app so i need to watch changes in the output of an API in real time so is there a way for me to do that ?

Comment: maybe you can store previous data in a variable and check the new data if it has difference with the previous data

Answer (score 0):

CASE 1: Well chrome do that for you, for example if the api response is unchanged then chrome returns 304 else it will return 200 OK.

CASE 2: If there is data changed by other calls then you can broadcast this change to all clients. For this you don't need API but socket connections.